# Does a weapon potential boss damage boost stack with a set boss damage boost?

Tags: maplestory

It has been tested that if you have multiple boss damage potentials on a weapon, only the lowest counts and they won't stack.

With the level 140 sets coming, there is a 30% boss damage boost on having the full set.

Would this stack with a weapons potential (going to 60% damage increase on bosses) or would only the lowest count?

Comment: "`It has been tested that if you have multiple boss damage potentials on a weapon, only the lowest counts and they won't stack.`" - [citation needed]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There used to be a glitch where only the lowest or highest would count.

However, I'm positively sure it has since been fixed and should be additive. I tested this out with Loveless Katara + Dagger. That's why you see a lot of people with over 300% in boss nowadays!